# How to render this conditional in Pug template

Tags: pug

In this block of code I am trying to render a partial called searchResult for each result in results, which is working.

However, I also really want to insert the error message in the screenshot. I would like it to appear once, if there is no result in results. This isn't working the way I would like. Instead of what I outlined, the text is permanently visible, and the searchTerm is the only thing that is inserted if there is no result in results.

How do I get it to display the error message *only if* there is no result in results?

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: Please post your actual code and not an image of your code.

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues.

First, your `block` needs to be your first object and EVERYTHING needs to be indented further to the right than that.

Second, your test for `if results` is testing for the existence of an object and not the size of the result set.  It still would evaluate to TRUE if zero results are returned, as `[]` (an empty array) is not null or empty.

You want to test like this:

```
if results.length > 0
  each result in results
else
  h2 There is no result
```